# SharePoint 2010 PowerPivot DAX functions

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, excel-services, powerpivot

Hi I have a PowerPivot with a calculated column that returns data via the RELATED function.  The columns works perfectly except for a handful of rows that return an empty cell.  After some troubleshooting I see that the cells that have blanks return FALSE to the ISTEXT function. What function can I use to convert my non-text values to text? I believe I need to use the FORMAT command but can't seem to find the correct format_string to apply to force the values to simple text.  Let me know if you have any thoughts and thanks in advance everyone!

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint is very loosly typed

```
 ="" & [NumberField]
```

Does a concatenation and returns a String

```
 =TEXT( [NumberField] )
```

Maybe works; it is usually used (with a second parameter) to format Dates and Numbers

https://www.365csi.nl/vm365com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List

Comment: Danny this is DAX not SharePoint :-)

Comment: All those MS products scripting/formula stuff are, more or less, based on VBscript

Answer (score 0):

Try the DAX function ISBLANK() . Here is the DAX function ref:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634204.aspx